# Make a direct database query

Tags: database

Basically I want to run this query against the current database and retrieve all node titles with node type of foo_type.

```
SELECT title FROM node WHERE type='foo_type' ORDER BY title ASC
```

How can I do this using db_query or any similar function? I tried doing the below but $result is empty.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT title FROM node WHERE type='foo_type' ORDER BY title ASC");
```

Please note any D6 and D7 differences if there are any.

Comment: The database documentation for Drupal 6 & 7 is vast - could you explain exactly what you don't understand please? What do you mean by 'empty'? What are you using to determine that?

Comment: dpm($result); Nothing there. I want to access all node titles with foo_type from $result;

Comment: And are you using Drupal 6 or 7 to get that result?

Comment: Drupal 6. But would also like to know how to do this on D7

Comment: The problem is that the subject is too vast to sum up in a single sentence, and it is heavily dependent on what you are trying to do.  It's like asking "What car should I buy and what are the differences?"  It depends, and there are *many* factors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Drupal 6:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT title FROM node WHERE type = '%s' ORDER BY title ASC", 'foo_type');
$titles = array();
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $titles[] = $row->title;
}
```

For Drupal 7 you have a bunch of options

Static:

```
$args = array(':type' => 'foo_type');
$titles = db_query("SELECT title FROM node WHERE type = :type ORDER BY title ASC", $args)->fetchCol();
```

Dynamic:

```
$titles = db_select('node')
  ->fields('node', array('title'))
  ->condition('type', 'foo_type')
  ->orderBy('title')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();
```

And a couple of less-direct methods...

EntityFieldQuery:

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('type', 'foo_type')
  ->propertyOrderBy('title');

$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
  $titles = array_map(function($x) { return $x->title; }, $nodes);
}
```

API (deprecated):

```
$nodes = entity_load('node', FALSE, array('type' => 'foo_type'));
$titles = array_map(function($x) { return $x->title; }, $nodes);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But on D7, what is that fetchCol() bit for?

Comment: Clive, good answer.  Would you also include a PDO example, just for completeness?

Comment: Just a helper method - if your query selects a single column it puts those values directly into a 1-d array for you

Comment: @corey not sure what you mean - D6 doesn't use PDO and all D7 queries are given to PDO anyway...do you mean a `db_select` example?

Comment: @Clive yes, a <code>db_select</code> example is what I mean.  <code>db_query</code> is a bit more lenient in that you can use MySQL-specific keywords, but the PDO object assembly provides for more robust, cross-database compliant code.  I would include it here myself, but the comments don't really allow for including code, and I don't feel that it warrants a separate answer.

Comment: @coreyp_1 Done, I've added a couple of other methods as well

Comment: @Clive Damn you're a beast.